# Why array.reduce returns NaN when I add 3rd object

Tags: javascript

Why array.reduce returns NaN when I add 3rd object? See example below. What am I missing?

```js
var x =[ 
 {Sum: 1},
 {Sum: 2},
 {Sum: 3}
]; 

var y = x.reduce((total, value) => total.Sum + value.Sum);

console.log(y);  // Why output is NaN?


x =[ 
 {Sum: 1},
 {Sum: 2},
]; 

y = x.reduce((total, value) => total.Sum + value.Sum);

console.log(y); // output = 3
```

Comment: Because on the second iteration `total` will be just the number `3` and you're getting `3.Sum` which is `undefined`.

Comment: Because in the second case `.reduce` only iterates once, which does not expose the mistake in your code. The mistake is only visible if `.reduce` iterates at least twice: `a + b` returns a number, which becomes the next value of `total`. And numbers don't have a `Sum` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either to return the same structure as both items,

```js
var x = [{ Sum: 1 }, { Sum: 2 }, { Sum: 3 }],
    y = x
        .reduce((a, b) => ({ Sum: a.Sum + b.Sum })) // reduce with the same structure
        .Sum;                                       // get value

console.log(y);
```

or take an *`initialValue`* of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for reducing, because you add a number and not a property.

```js
var x = [{ Sum: 1 }, { Sum: 2 }, { Sum: 3 }],
    y = x.reduce((total, object) => total + object.Sum, 0); // start with zero

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your code with 2 objects seems to work, is because when you use the `reduce` function with no initial value, the accumulator takes the first array value as its initial value, in this case `{ Sum: 1}`. So on the first iteration of your reduce function, `total.Sum + value.Sum` is `1 + 2`, which gives 3. There are no more objects in the array, the iteration ends, and the error is not seen.

However, once you have 3 objects, on the next iteration, your accumulator is no longer in object form, it is now a number (3). You then try to get `total.Sum` which now is `3.Sum`, which means nothing.

For clarity, let's add the initial value of the accumulator as the second argument of your reduce function. Assuming you want a number to represent the total, let's use 0 to start off with.

As you move through the reduce function, you want to add the value of each `value.Sum` to your total, and then return the `total`. This should not be `total.Sum`, since `total` is not an object.

Here is a working example, with console logs for clarity as to what is happening in the reduce functions:

```js
var x =[ 
 {Sum: 1},
 {Sum: 2},
 {Sum: 3}
]; 

var y = x.reduce((total, value) => {
 console.log('1 -->', total, value);
 return total + value.Sum
}, 0);

console.log('final y value -->', y); 


x =[ 
 {Sum: 1},
 {Sum: 2},
]; 

y = x.reduce((total, value) => {
 console.log('2 -->', total, value);
 return total + value.Sum
}, 0);

console.log('final y value -->', y);
```